# Function literal with call-by-name parameter

Tags: scala

How does one define an anonymous function with call-by-name parameters in scala?

I tried the following:

```
val fun = (x: Boolean, y: =>Int) => if(x) y else 0
```

This works well with call-by-value y, but not with call-by-name. Why?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It can be done, but in a slightly different way: declare the type separately from the parameters:

```
val fun: (Boolean, => Int) => Int = (x, y) => if (x) y else 0
```