# Explicit type of call-by-name function parameters

Tags: scala

Given a method

```
def twice(s: => Int): Int = s + s
```

I can get a `Function1` of type `(=> Int) => Int` by writing:

```
val valTwiceA: (=> Int) => Int = twice
// or
val valTwiceC: (=> Int) => Int = {(byName/*:(=>Int)*/) => twice(byName)}
```

**I guess there is no way to explicitly specify the type of `byName`.**

1. Am I right?
2. What is the proper way to explicitly specify the type of `byName`?
   `(byName: (=>Int))` yields an error *"no by-name parameter type allowed here"*

*code template:*

```
// scalaVersion "2.10.4" or "2.11.1"
import org.scalatest.FreeSpec

class ByNameTest extends FreeSpec {
  def twice(s: => Int): Int = s + s
  val valTwiceA: (=> Int) => Int = twice
  val valTwiceB: (=> Int) => Int = {byName => twice(byName)}
  val valTwiceC: (=> Int) => Int = {(byName/*:(=>Int)*/) => twice(byName)}

  "twice" in {
    val it = Iterator from 1
    assert(valTwiceA(it.next) === 3)
    assert(valTwiceB(it.next) === 7)
    assert(valTwiceC(it.next) === 11)
  }
}
```

Comment: btw, there is also `val twiceD = twice _`

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168897/function-literal-with-call-by-name-parameter) have your answer?

Comment: @Ben Unfortunately, I can't "accept" a comment, but this seems to be the answer. However, I miss the reason in D.C.Sobral's answer.