# issue with by-name parameter in scala when using function literal

Tags: scala

```
// Version 1
val emptyValblock: ( => Int) => Int = (x) => x + 2 // OK

// Version 2
val emptyValblock: ( => Int) => Int =  (x: => Int ) => x + 2 // Compile error
```

Why does version 1 works and not version 2?

I can't see why making the type explicit prevents the function from compiling.

Comment: Yes it does many thanks. I did not find that answer, found another one originally https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168897/function-literal-with-call-by-name-parameter.